# My form close button doesn't work with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an X button to close a form with Javascript but it's not working and I can't figure out why. Once I open it I can't close. 
I'm just putting here the code for the button and the form, not the whole page behind it. Hope someone can help me.

html

```
<div class="open-btn">
  <button id="show-modal"><strong>Open Form</strong></button>
</div>
<div class="modal modal--hidden">
 <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="close"> 
          <i class="fas fa-times">X</i>
        </div>
        <h1>Ask away</h1>
        <form id="submit">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Subject">
      <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#show-modal {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(48, 51, 54);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(48, 51, 54);
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.open-btn {
  padding-top: 30px;
}


.modal {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal_content {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

.modal_content h1 {
  font-family: "Ibarra Real Nova", serif;
  color: rgba(40, 44, 48, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.close {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(234, 203, 193, 0.4);
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.submit:hover {
  background-color: rgba(143, 126, 121, 0.4);
}

.modal--hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("show-modal").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "flex";
});
document.querySelector(".fas fa-times").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.dispay = "none";
});
```

https://codepen.io/joanaoli09/pen/JjYoZoa

Comment: It is not possible to add event listener on hidden element, instead you should call function on click `<i class="fas fa-times" onclick="closeMe()">X</i>` and `function closeMe() {
  debugger;
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";
}`

Comment: Also incorrect spelling of "display" in second listener in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("show-modal").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "flex";
});
function closeMe() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#show-modal {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(48, 51, 54);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(48, 51, 54);
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.open-btn {
  padding-top: 30px;
}


.modal {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal_content {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

.modal_content h1 {
  font-family: "Ibarra Real Nova", serif;
  color: rgba(40, 44, 48, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.close {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(234, 203, 193, 0.4);
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.submit:hover {
  background-color: rgba(143, 126, 121, 0.4);
}

.modal--hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="open-btn">
  <button id="show-modal"><strong>Open Form</strong></button>
</div>
<div class="modal modal--hidden">
 <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="close"> 
          <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="closeMe()">X</i>
        </div>
        <h1>Ask away</h1>
        <form id="submit">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Subject">
      <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First your click position and `X` were different. Though you was attaching event on `i` but was clicking on `X`. In these case place `X` as a text of `i`. Secondly it has to be `document.querySelector(".fas.fa-times")` instead of `document.querySelector(".fas fa-times")` and thirdly use `classList.toggle` instead of adding class to style attribute

```js
document.getElementById("show-modal").addEventListener("click", function() {
  togglElementeClass();
});
document.querySelector(".fas.fa-times").addEventListener("click", function() {
  togglElementeClass();
});

function togglElementeClass() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").classList.toggle('flex');
}
```

```css
#show-modal {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(48, 51, 54);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(48, 51, 54);
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.open-btn {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.modal {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal_content {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

.modal_content h1 {
  font-family: "Ibarra Real Nova", serif;
  color: rgba(40, 44, 48, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.close {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(234, 203, 193, 0.4);
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.submit:hover {
  background-color: rgba(143, 126, 121, 0.4);
}

.modal--hidden {
  display: none;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.fas.fa-times {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="open-btn">
  <button id="show-modal"><strong>Open Form</strong></button>
</div>
<div class="modal modal--hidden">
  <div class="modal_content">
    <div class="close">
      <i class="fas fa-times">X</i>
    </div>
    <h1>Ask away</h1>
    <form id="submit">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Subject">
      <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunaly none of these work, it appears an error on the console of  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" at ```document.querySelector(".fas.fa-times").addEventListener("click", function() {
  togglElementeClass(); }); ```
I pasted it exactly how it is here.

Comment: @JoanaOliveira checked your pen , still now i see yu are not using toggleClass and have not updated css

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your second event listener:

you are trying to get element by `".fa fa-times"` which is not a valid selector for your cross element.

Just replace `".fa fa-times"` with `".fa.fa-times` or `".fa-times"` and it should work perfectly.

```
document.querySelector(".fa-times").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Have a look https://codepen.io/sonu247/pen/qBOEKmg this works for me.

Comment: yeah, it works on pencode but still doesn't work with me, it gives me an error on the console...

Comment: Looks like, I have also made spelling mistake in `display`. I have updated the answer, and it should work for you now.

Comment: Yeah I've realised that too and fix that and would still not work, so strange. Anyway used another method and it ended up working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

u have two mistake about closing event. one of them is your class name u need to write fa-times another one u wrote dispay it is wrong

```
document.querySelector(".fa-times").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("casa")
   document.querySelector(".modal").style.display = "none";

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all getting elements by  general classes like `fas fa` which third party libraries provide (in this case font-awesome) is not a good practice. Because it's possible to use the same classes for another element in page. I suggest using an id for this situation or a specific class. Another problem is that we usually use `<button>` for actions not `<i>`.`<i>` tag is not action ready so by clicking on it you actually click on its content(X) not the  tag. Now the problem in ur code is that when you set display:flex in your JS the element gets the style and when you  `document.querySelector(".modal").style.dispay = "none";` you don't clear the previous style (display:flex) so both of them are applied. You should clear display:flex then apply display:none or make a class like `d-flex` which toggels by click.

**In HTML**

```
<div class="close">
  <i id="close-btn" class="fas fa-times">X</i>
</div>
```

**In CSS**

```
.d-flex
{
  display:flex !important;
}
```

**In Js**

```
document.getElementById("show-modal").addEventListener("click", function() {
  togglElementeClass();
});
document.querySelector("#close-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  togglElementeClass();
});

function togglElementeClass() {
  document.querySelector(".modal").classList.toggle('d-flex');
}
```